# Uploading xml file from system and sending it to api in request body in angular (in JSON Format)

Tags: angular

can someone guide me on how can I upload an XML file from my angular UI as input and send it in the request body in JSON format to my backhand post API. I am using angular 10 version

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Choose File</label>
    <input type="file"
           id="file"
           (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
</div>
```

**Step 2: Component**

```
  handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
        let fileToUpload = files.item(0);
       this.fileUploadService.postFile(fileToUpload ).subscribe(data => {
      // do something, if upload success
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

**Step 3:**
create a service to make post call add the following code

```
postFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<boolean> {
    const endpoint = 'your-destination-url';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    return this.httpClient
      .post(endpoint, formData, { headers: yourHeadersConfig })
      .map(() => { return true; })
      .catch((e) => this.handleError(e));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @krishna .To add it to it how can I send this from data in JSON format to my api

Comment: @PriyankaSahu we cannot sent the xml file as JSON format we need to use form Data,added post man screenshot for reference

Comment: i dont want to send the file as json format but overall i need to send the form data as json format.For example i have 2 input filelds and one file upload option in my ui so i want to send all those in json format .example:  {
 "Templatename": "test",
 "source": "testfile",
 "xmlfile": ""
}

Comment: ` const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Templatename', 'test');
    formData.append('source', 'testfile');
    formData.append('xmlfile', fileToUpload);`. hope this helps you